# How to search email by attachment name in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, search, attachments

I know that somewhere in my mailbox there is an email with an attachment of which I remember (part of) the name. Is it possible to locate this email automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the add-on:

**Expression Search / GMailUI**

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmailui/

Search with the format:

```
file:partoffilenamehere
```

Comment: Since there is an add-on for this, I guess there's no native way :(
This works perfectly!

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It returns three emails, none of which have any attachments

Comment: Ok so 1. This extension only adds to the Quick Search, not the main search.  2. "Note 2: If you want search all folders using expression, you can create a virtual folder manually (Ctrl+Shift+F) with 'Match all messages', then using expression search in the virtual folder."  3. Different versions are compatible with different versions of Thunderbird https://github.com/wangvisual/expression-search/tree/master/beta https://github.com/wangvisual/expression-search/tree/master/releases

Comment: This extension is obsolete and doesn't support modern versions of Thunderbird